# I am getting an issue in Swipe view inside listview , when Item source is changed dynamically

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, swipeview

#### Description

I used Swipe view inside Listview , in swipe view used frame as content and image in swipe right item view . When changed Itemsource dynamically and swipe right , the image is not shown instead another frame is created under this frame.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. create listview with Swipe view in Item templapte ,  frame as content of swipe view.
2. Change item source dynamically.
3. Swipe the item , image is not shown another frame is shown.

#### Expected Behavior

The image need to shown

#### Actual Behavior

Another frame is shown.

#### Basic Information

- Version with issue: 5.0.0.1558 - pre , 4.8.0.1687
- Last known good version: did not checked
- Platform Target Frameworks:

  - iOS:
  - Android:  10
  - UWP:
- Android Support Library / AndroidX Version:
- NuGet Packages:
- Affected Devices: Emulator Pixel 2

#### Environment

About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info [button]
Visual Studio for Mac: Visual Studio > About Visual Studio > Show Details > Copy Information [button]
2. Paste into the code block below (between ```)
-->

#### Build Logs

Projects > Build
- On Visual Studio for Windows: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run
On Visual Studio for Windows you also want to add `-v -v -v -v` to the mtouch additional arguments by right-clicking the project in the solution explorer and selecting `Properties`.
-->

#### Screenshots

Expected Behavior
[image]
[image]
[image]

Actual Behavior

[image]

[image]

[Android Emulator - pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28_5554 2020-12-08 18-02-18.zip](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/5659257/Android.Emulator.-.pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28_5554.2020-12-08.18-02-18.zip)

#### Reproduction Link

#### Workaround

Comment: You mean that you open swipview, but swipview will be closed when you change listview itemsource? You want to swipview remain open? am I right?

Comment: No @CherryBu-MSFT, I am changing the item source in a button click, after that, while trying to swipe, I am able to see duplicate control behind the view cell.

Comment: Can you provide one sample at github, I will download your sample to test, because I can not reproduce your problem.